# Are there any password managers that rarely fail to fill in login credentials?

Tags: password-manager

I'm probably looking for ones that go beyond ignoring `AutoComplete=off` in the HTML.

My password manager seems to be getting less and less able to log me in to sites automatically, or semi-automatically.

So I'm wondering - Are many password managers getting worse and worse at filling in login credentials?  (Are sites getting better at blocking 'em?) Are any still good?

DETAILS:
I use Lastpass.  My `Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable AutoFill` setting is NOT checked.  But on more and more sites/more and more of the time, it acts as if it is checked.  I make sure, if I have more than one credential for a site, only one matching site has Autologin enabled.  Often, credentials don't fill, even when I ask Lastpass to fill in a particular credential.  *I can provide specific examples (sites, plugin and browser info) if that would be helpful; just ask.  But really that would be appropriate if I was asking here for troubleshooting help, and I'm not. There are already answers/guides/forums for that, e.g. on the Lastpass site, and I'm not having luck with the info there.*
Some related questions provide relevant info:
(User's) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926267/password-manager-no-longer-works-with-password-field-after-redesign

So I'm wondering if it's time to change password manager because there are ones that still work well, or if this problem is not limited to my password manager.  Hence this question.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with 1Password not filling in credentials.

Answer (score 2):

[KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org) has [autotype](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/wiki/Autotype-Custom-Sequence) which acts as though you're typing your login. It should never fail. The only exception I've seen is when `tab` does not jump from the username field to the password field, which is the default autotype sequence. It's rare. On sites or apps where it does you can customize the sequence.